# Migrating solidity program testrpc+truffle - Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" at Object.InvalidResponse

Tags: truffle, testrpc, truffle-migration, migration

I am trying to make a truffle application.

> truffle compile : working fine making a 'build' folder with .json files in it.
>   truffle migrate : Gives the following error
>   I am running testrpc in another powershell window.
>   OS :  Windows 8.1

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\RK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js
:35:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\RK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\web3
\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:116:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\RK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\l
ib\xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\RK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js
:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (C:\Users\RK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xh
r2.js:544:12)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:414
:24)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Comment: i'm having the same issue when im not connected to the internet. running local testrpc. There has been some discussion on gitter that starting testrpc in the same dir as you migrate helps however it didnt make any difference for me. have you made any progress?

Comment: @Andrew Welcome Andrew. I'm just tidying up a little since this isn't an answer. I realize you might not be able to leave comments until you have more points on this site. Not a problem. :-)   i'm having the same issue. There has been some discussion on gitter that starting testrpc in the same dir as you migrate helps however it didnt make any difference for me. have you made any progress?

Comment: I usually have this error when testRPC dies in the background.
Have you checked the console output of testrpc?
What's your testrpc version? I've encountered more testrpc crashes with newer versions but the latest 4.0.1 is fairly stable again

Comment: I am having the same problem, did anyone get the solution? I have tried using `ganache` and `testrpc` both. But, neither worked. Also, I tried starting `testrpc` in my current project directory but it too didn't do any good. I am questioning my life right now :D

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Rob, running `testrpc` from the same folder in which `truffle console` is run solved the issue in my case